# Find intersection in one hash map values

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, intersection

I have a problem to solve if at least one of the values matches against other values

```
HashMap<Long, Set<String> map
```

In this below Example - My hashmap contains 3 records with values

1. (a,b)
2. (a)
3. (a)

If you take a look at this, we need to find intersection value -- "a" exists in all hash map values so the result should be "a". How to code this logic efficiently in Hashmap.

Thanks in advance and appreciate for the help!

First scenario is for : Ignore empty

Second scenario : -- Do not ignore empty

[image]

Comment: What is the type of your HashMap?

Comment: Hashmap<Long, Set<String>>

Answer (score 3):

### Scenario 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Long, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1L, Set.of("a", "b"));
    map.put(2L, Set.of("a"));
    map.put(3L, Set.of("a"));
    Set<String> result = map.values().stream()
        .reduce((a, b) -> {
            Set<String> c = new HashSet<>(a);
            c.retainAll(b);
            return c;
        })
        .orElseGet(HashSet::new);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

output:

```
[a]
```

Or

```
static <T> Set<T> intersection(Collection<Set<T>> sets) {
    Iterator<Set<T>> iterator = sets.iterator();
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) return new HashSet<>();
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<>(iterator.next());
    while (iterator.hasNext())
        result.retainAll(iterator.next());
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Long, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1L, Set.of("a", "b"));
    map.put(2L, Set.of("a"));
    map.put(3L, Set.of("a"));
    System.out.println(intersection(map.values()));
}
```

### Scenario 1

```
    Set<String> result = map.values().stream()
        .filter(set -> !set.isEmpty())
        .reduce((a, b) -> {
            Set<String> c = new HashSet<>(a);
            c.retainAll(b);
            return c;
        })
        .orElseGet(HashSet::new);
```

Or

```
static <T> Set<T> intersection(Collection<Set<T>> sets) {
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<>();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Set<T> set : sets) {
        if (!set.isEmpty()) {
            if (first)
                result.addAll(set);
            else
                result.retainAll(set);
            first = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I was thinking something along the lines of stream() and reduce()... how do you test your code? Do you use an online interpreter somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really worked and saved my day. Just one more help on the same logic. if other bucket values are empty, how can I get result A? I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help u.

```
    public static List<String> match(HashMap<String, String> map) {
        if (map.size() == 0) return new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        String[] first = list.get(0).split(",");
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(first));

        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String[] vals = list.get(0).split(",");
            Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < vals.length; j++) {
                if (set.contains(vals[j])) {
                    tempSet.add(vals[j]);
                }
            }
            // can't match all, return empty list
            if (tempSet.size() == 0) return new ArrayList<>();
            set = tempSet;
        }

        return new ArrayList<>(set);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).